# Store not being read or recognized

Tags: extjs, store, extjs4.2

I get this error when I try to start up my ExtJS 4.2 app:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined`

I've double checked all my `store` ids and and names to ensure that they are all spelt correctly but I'm still having this issue :(. Is there anything else I could try to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All models, stores, views and controller defined in app.js?

Answer (score 8):

I typically get this error when one of my grids is referencing a store that has not been defined in either the controller instantiating the view or app.js (depending on how the app is structured)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, usign Sencha Architect 3.5, I had to drag to the Store Section the store and it works again. I didn't know when the Application loss the relation with the store but doing that it's working again.